# Making mediaserver immediately scan a file created through ADB

Tags: adb, automation, media-scanner

The mediaserver in my stock and rooted Android 6.0.1 (running in Nexus 6) doesn't detect new files created or moved to into /sdcard using adb. It doesn't detect until I do a soft/full reboot which I find unacceptable to perform.

I'm able to manually run mediaserver using command-line to begin file scanning again<sup><sup>#</sup></sup> *and I want this to be done automatically and immediately whenever a new file is created under /sdcard*. <strike>At the moment, I have Tasker run the mediaserver whenever USB cable is unplugged.</strike><sup><sup>*</sup></sup>

The obvious choice here seems to be an automation app of which I tried Tasker and [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate), and both amazingly failed to detect new files, particularly under /sdcard/Music, when created through adb. However, if an app created files in any directory under */sdcard* those two apps immediately detected the changes. I also tried pushing files to */storage/emulated/0/* instead of */sdcard/* and made corresponding changes in those two apps' triggers.That step didn't benefit me.

It is to be noted that I observed this problem in stock Android 5.1.1 and a CM13 snapshot build as well.

So, how do I achieve the goal?

#### Update

I'm aware of the possibility of creating an alias in the OS running in my PC which would execute a script providing a way to push the file as well as run the mediaserver. <strike>However, it is something I would like to avoid as much as possible.</strike>

<sup><sup>*</sup></sup> I was using it but later switched to a script executed from PC using an alias. However, ***I do not want to depend upon any of the two methods***. My fingers are comfortable with typing *adb push* instead of *adb_push* or some other but single word.

#### Update 2

- I do not intend to restrict myself to a particular directory, such as Download and neither pushing files into the latter actually works.
- I would like to stress that I'm not asking for *how to run mediaserver*. That I already know. All I'm looking for is: Whenever I do `adb push FILE /sdcard/FILE` the mediaserver should automatically and immediately kick in and scans the file. Regardless of any perceivable performance issue, I want it to kick in every single time.

#### Update 3

Okay, *I may be using an incorrect term*. Perhaps *mediaserver* and *media scanner* are terms for two different things in Android. In the case of confusion, please stick with
"media scanner" for both the current revision and the bounty note.

#### Update 4

<sup><sup>#</sup></sup> Courtesy of androidyue for [this helpful resource](http://droidyue.com/blog/2014/01/19/scan-media-files-in-android/), any of the following command in preformatted text is what I can use in my device to make media scanner scan the file.

```
# FILE_PATH refers to the location of pushed file in Android. E.g. /sdcard/Music/lolcat.mp3

am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -n com.android.providers.media/.MediaScannerReceiver
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE -d file://FILE_PATH   # guaranteed to work. See https://goo.gl/lH0CLT for proof.
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file://FILE_PATH
```

#### Update 5

Per the [suggestion](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141142/making-mediaserver-immediately-scan-a-file-created-through-adb?noredirect=1#comment182420_141142) from Manubhargav, I tried Sarkie's MTPFix available [here](https://github.com/Sarkie/mtpfix/tree/master/release). It didn't work, both in stock Android 6.0.1 and CM13. I saw the following entry when I enabled the service for that app.

```
04-07 09:38:14.771  3383  3383 I MTPService: Watching /storage/emulated/0
```

I later pushed a sound file into */storage/emulated/0/* and nothing showed up in my music player. Logcat also didn't display anything useful either.

By the way, this app [uses FileObserver](https://github.com/Sarkie/mtpfix/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/sarkie/utils/RecursiveFileObserver.java), so I'm not surprised if it couldn't detect files created using adb, since it is the same issue with the automation apps I tried.

---

**Note:** Please post an answer only when you've tested it yourself. Thank you!

Comment: I found this, it's beyond my scope of knowledge (the answers point back to some MediaScannerConnection tool in developer tools) but it might help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147536/how-to-trigger-mediascan-on-nexus-7

Comment: ***Note to readers: please don't suggest me to compile adb. That I'm not going to do even if you provide details for it.***

Comment: [Sarkie's MTP fix](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282#c42)(APK to be installed on device) helps mediaserver scan the files copied under MTP. *It scans recursively External Storage Directory and then adding to Media Scanner once a file has been created.*  It might help with ADB too, worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it seems the answer is trivial. My fingers don't have to lose the comfort of typing `adb push`, yet I would be able to cause media scanner scan my pushed file, *automatically and immediately*. Here's my script tweaked to my needs:

<sub>(**Note**: root access is *not* required in Android)</sub>

```
#!/bin/bash

function push_file () {
    target="${@: -1}";
    file_path="${@: -2:1}";
    [[ "$prog_bar" == "-p" ]] && adb "$@" || $call_adb push -p "$file_path" "$target";
}

function broadcast () {
    file_name="$(basename "$file_path")";
    [[ `echo "${target: -1}"` != "/" ]] && unset file_name;
    [[ `echo "${target:0:1}"` != "/"  ]] && target="/${target}";
    $call_adb shell 'am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE -d '"\"file://$target$file_name\""'' > /dev/null;
}

if [[ "$1" == "-s" ]]; then
    if [[ "$3" == "push" ]]; then
        prog_bar="$4";
        call_adb="adb -s $2";
        push_file "$@" && broadcast;
    else
        adb "$@";
    fi
elif [[ "$1" == "push" ]]; then
        prog_bar="$2";
        call_adb="adb";
        push_file "$@" && broadcast;
else
    adb "$@";
fi
```

I then setup an alias named *adb* in *.bashrc* like this:

```
alias adb='bash FILE'  # FILE refers the file path of the said script
```

This was possible thanks to the very helpful article: [Handling positional parameters](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams#mass_usage) at Bash Hackers Wiki.

**Note**: the script  more or less requires a *nix based OS in PC with version 4.x of Bash installed and support for *.bashrc*. If you intend to use the script, you're encouraged to edit it to suit your working style.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the media scanner works exactly,
I think that the media scanner constantly updates the Download folder inside internal storage...

if something doesn't show up inside another folder, i copy it to the download folder and it triggers media scanner...

Try using Download folder inside Internal Storage as the absolute path

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. BTW, did you yourself try this approach using ADB?

Comment: adb shell am broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED               .........From http://stackoverflow.com/a/19435985/6116090

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. *I've virtually no problem in running the mediaserver manually.* My question is about doing things automatically without any intervention from me. It means, as soon as I do `adb push FILE /sdcard/DIR/` mediaserver should kick in and scan the file.

Comment: Have you tried making a batch file to automate the script.. Windows is commandlist.bat and Linux is commandlist.sh

Comment: Yes. I'm currently using a simple script and I don't want to depend upon it. I've even addressed this in my question. Please check the content below *Update* in my question.